# AWS API Gateway body map wildcard

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have set up an API on AWS API Gateway which uses content negotiation to provide two means by which to get hold of some data.

My problem is that because the [default `Content-Type` header appears to be `application/json`](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=215471), the markup example below is returned as `application/json` and therefore just displayed rather than rendered.

The body mapping template `text/html` tries an exact match on the `Accept` header sent by the browser. For example, Chrome sends

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
```

Which clearly `!== text/html`. That said, when I send a request such as the above, the correct response is shown, but the wrong content type header is displayed.

My options would appear to be

1. Find some way of setting the default to `text/html`
2. Find a means by which to make a wildcard or regex work. E.g. `text/*`

I have tried the above to no avail but I'm hoping I'm missing something.

---

Response examples

- One responds with JSON (`Accept: application/json`)

  ```
  {
    "id": "d4ef7d3f-f2..."
  }
  ```
- Another is markup and some JS which sends a `postMessage`. `Accept: text/html`

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <script>
        parent.postMessage({"id": "d4ef7d3f-f2..."}, "...", window);
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
  ```

Gist of the API Gateway Swagger

https://gist.github.com/benswinburne/3a212c936e1d97fe8e17352269d6edb6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Gateway support for content negotiation is currently limited.

I would suggest against serving content directly with API Gateway, and instead to use a thin client layer to control the calls to API Gateway. This allows full control of Accept/Content-Type headers, amongst other things.

As an example, we commonly see simple SPAs, commonly hosted on an S3 site, with a javascript client to call API Gateway.

Alternatively, you can override the default mapping for the Content-Type header in your method response.

Edit to explain how I implemented it based on this answer.

1. Add method response `Content-Type`
2. Add an integration response header mapping

   ```
   Content-Type => integration.response.body.contentType
   ```
3. Ensure that the header param is mapped in a body mapping template in integration request for all Content Types you're using.
4. Update the lambda function to return a content type property, per the example below

---

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var contentType = this.negotiateContentType(event.params.header.Accept);

    // abridged

    context.done(null, {contentType}); // abridged
};

exports.negotiateContentType = (header) => {
    var contentType = 'text/html';

    if (header.match(/json/ig)) {
        contentType = 'application/json';
    }

    return contentType;
}
```

---

If you don't want the content type in your response, you can set up a body mapping template per content type in the integration response.

For example

```
// All properties
$input.json('$')

// Custom output
{
    "myproperty": $input.json('$.myproperty')
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan - your last statement gave me the idea above which I've added to your answer to fully explain how I got it to work for others. Unfortunately using an SPA as a proxy wouldn't fit my needs as there are 302 redirects as well as actual content which all need to be on the same domain. A proxy would mean I'd have to redirect the browser after loading the content and proxying the request with JS or a meta refresh which would be too slow. Furthermore, dropping cookies becomes problematic with that approach unless i redirect via yet another URL.